# System-wide keyboard emulation of mouse scroll

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I would like to emulate mouse scrolling through a keyboard shortcut. What I mean by that is whether I have a browser or terminal open, I want to be able to scroll through it exactly the same way I would scroll using my mouse.

I know that many terminals allow to scroll using `Ctrl+Page Up/Down`, however it still would not be what I'm looking for, as I need single line scroll, working not only in a terminal but in all of the applications. I have a trackpad which supports scrolling on my laptop and a USB mouse which also supports scrolling.

I am using Ubuntu Linux LTS 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject input events with [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). You can invoke commands on a key press with [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html). Put something like this in your `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool click 4"
control+shift+prior
"xdotool click 5"
control+shift+next
```